# Update all href attributes

Tags: jquery, html, string, find, href

I have variable named `a` (`var a = "test"`) and I need to put it in all the `href` attribute of all `a` elements on a page which contain the word `ONE`. All `href` values are not the same but always contains the word `ONE`

For example I want to change this:

```
href="/page2.php?how=GO-ONE-24-title-stay"
```

To this:

```
href="/page2.php?how=GO-ONE-test-24-title-stay"
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: The question is how can I find all href contains this word and put this variable there :)

Comment: Do you want to put the *word* 'test' in to the URL, or the *value* of the 'test' variable in the URL? Your second example isn't clear as it conflicts with what you say above.

Comment: I am sorry this is little confusing... I named the variable same like the value - var test="test" - so I will rename **var test** to **var a**

Comment: Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I added an answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
$('a[href*="ONE"]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('ONE', 'ONE-test'));
});
```

Your example is a bit misleading, so if you meant that the test value is a variable, then you would need something like this:

```
var add = 'test';

$('a[href*="ONE"]').each(function(){
    var currentHref = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', currentHref.replace('ONE', 'ONE-' + add));
});
```

Comment: I would add that you could change your selector to `$('a[href*="ONE"]')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var a ="test" ;

    $('a').each(function(){
        this.href = this.href.replace('ONE', 'ONE-'+a);
    });
});
```

Here is a working [example](http://jsbin.com/vihesudebu/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by providing a function to the `attr()` method; there's no need for an explicit loop. Try this:

```
var a = 'test';
$('a[href*="-ONE-"]').attr('href', function(i, href) {
    return href.replace('-ONE-', '-ONE-' + a + '-';
});
```

Note that the initial jQuery selector restricts the elements to be amended to only those who contain `ONE-` within the `href` attribute.

Comment: If she needs this change in **all** her `href`'s, what's the point on doing the replacement in execution time? Using an editor supporting RegExp replacements she just could find `href="([^\"]+)ONE([^\"]+)"` and replace with `href="$1ONE-test$2"`. Doesn't she?

Comment: Are you suggestion you parse HTML with RegEx? Because that's a really bad idea.

Comment: No, i'm not suggesting this. I mean, if I'm understanding the problem, it looks like she wants to change all `href`'s to point some kind of test environment, so why overload the site making this replacement with jQuery in execution time? She could just find and replace her `href`'s in her editor. She just needs and editor supporting RegExp replacement (like Sublime Text)... Or maybe I'm just not getting her needs... :)

Comment: @JordiNebot Ah, I see. In that case I agree completely. I can only assume the OP has a variable which can change at runtime which needs to be placed in the attribute

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var test = "test";
$("a").each(function() {
  var href_val = $(this).prop("href");
  if(href_val.indexOf("ONE") >= 0){
  href_val = href_val.replace("ONE", "ONE-"+test);
  $(this).prop("href", href_val);
  }
});
});
```